# how can a lock statement exit without releasing the lock?

Tags: c#

I have a strange problem, a deadlock problem, where if I pause the program using Visual Studio and inspect the threads I can only see two threads waiting on the lock. No thread appears to be inside the lock scope! Is Visual Studio just lying or how can a lock statement exit without releasing the lock?

Thanks

Comment: Visual studio might be lying :) but are you sure you always release the lock? Are there more than just one lock?

Comment: I'm using the standard lock statement so the lock should always be released ..... using the try, finally that the lock expands into.

Comment: What object are you locking on?

Comment: Locking on just a; private readonly object _lockObj = new object();

Comment: Are there actually only the two threads running, and not a third (UI?) thread holding the lock (or otherwise screwing with your synchronization)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any explicit calls to `Monitor.Enter` / `Monitor.TryEnter` in your code? Can you see the stack traces for those waiting threads? If so, look at where they're waiting - that should make it obvious.

Comment: I am just using the standard lock statement. No Monitor methods. I can see two threads waiting on the same lock object. Their call stacks look fine but I can't see any thread inside the lock. hrmmm ... no sure what's going on.

Comment: Ah, so they're waiting at "normal" lock statements, but you don't know why they're waiting? I see. Hmm... how reproducible is this?

Comment: Yes, I can't see why 2 threads are waiting. No thread seems to be inside the lock ... as far as Visual Studio's Threads window lets me anyway. I have reproduced it twice, with the same results. But there should be no way this is happening right? Thanks

Comment: @CodingThunder: Not if they're genuinely waiting. I would suggest you try to work out a surefire way of reproducing it - and then try to take other threads out of the picture. Just to check, are these threads definitely waiting on the *same* lock? I don't suppose they could have deadlocked, could they? (Each owning a different thread and waiting on the other.)

Answer (score 9):

This can happen under the following circumstances. Suppose you have

```
Enter();
try
{
   Foo();
}
finally
{
   Exit();
}
```

and a thread abort exception is thrown after the Enter but before the try. Now the monitor has been entered but the finally will never run because the exception was thrown before the try.

We've fixed this flaw in C# 4. In C# 4 the lock statement is now generated as

```
bool mustExit = false;
try
{
    Enter(ref mustExit);
    Foo();
}
finally
{
    if (mustExit) Exit();
}
```

Things can still go horribly wrong of course; aborting a thread is no guarantee that the thread ever aborts, that finally blocks ever run, and so on. You could end up in the unhandled exception event handler with the lock still taken.  But this is at least a little better.

Comment: I was just about to post the same thing, because I remembered reading a note to this effect in "The C# Programming Language, 3rd Ed.", but you beat me to it.  When I looked up the reference, though, the note I remembered (on page 386 in section 8.12) was actually written by you, so I guess you *really* beat me to it... :-)

Answer (score 2):

This can happen if you manually call [`Monitor.Enter(something)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de0542zz.aspx) without calling [`Monitor.Exit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.exit.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Are you by any chance calling yield return from within a lock statement from a thread pool thread?

If that is the case, you may want to look at [Yielding surprises](http://alfredmyers.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!19D601BD22E34F6E!655.entry)

This blog post describes a bug (I got locked out) I encountered when I combined those three things the wrong way. Luckly I was albe to resolve the issue with a small change to the code.